# Celery on app servers with periodic task, without duplicate task execution

Tags: python, celery

We plan to have celary running on an app that is replicated as multiple instances.

Will the scheduler still be able to handle a periodic task (e.g 30 minutes) between those multiple instances without being ran too many times in error?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If by scheduler you mean celery beat, it doesn't handle the tasks itself.
Instead, it sends a new message to your message queue that your workers will then process.

If you configured your workers to listen on the same queue and the beat to send to this same queue, everything should be well.

PS: You can have multiple workers but you should have only one beat. Check progress on https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/251 for multiple beats.

Comment: sounds like we should create a new component then instead for now